# Issues with Signin - Chapter 8 of ROR Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies, railstutorial.org

I am trying to get a user to log in using the login form created and I've followed the steps in the Tut to get the session cookies etc. (see code below) and I get this error when I go to submit a login form: (plus is redirects the page to --> :3000/sessions)

---

**NameError in SessionsController#create**

**undefined local variable or method `user' for #**

**Rails.root: C:/rails_projects/sample_app**

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:13:in `current_user='

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:5:in `sign_in'

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'

---

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",

"authenticity_token"=>"9q8ye89fq0394u790qjfq0ngq4t=",

"session"=>{"email"=>"example@example.com",

"password"=>"[FILTERED]"},

"commit"=>"Sign in"}

---

/sessions_helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?  
    end

    def current_user=(uaser)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end

end
```

/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new

    end

    def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy

    end

end
```

/routes.rb file:

```
  SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root :to => 'static_pages#home'

  match '/help', to: "static_pages#help"

  match '/about', to: "static_pages#about"

  match '/contact', to: "static_pages#contact"

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', method: "delete"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
def current_user=(uaser)
```

It should be

```
def current_user=(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Change:

`def current_user=(uaser)`

to

`def current_user=(user)`